# Versioning of debian packaging Information

Tags: git, debian-packaging

I'm developing certain scripts and small software packages which I also package as debian packages.

The code is maintained in git and I create new release tarballs with an make target and git-archive. This tarball is then fed to "uupdate -u .tar.gz" to update from the previous packaged version. This far everything works great and exactly as I want it to.

Now the tricky part: I want to put the packaging information, i.e. everything below debian/ (e.g. mypackage-0.4.3/debian/*), under version control, too. I'd just use git, but that would break dpkg because it would cry about the unknown files in its directory.

My question:

**What is the easiest way to put my debian/ folders under version control (with git)?**

Please note that I'd like to keep my source code and packaging information in separate repositories, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the package [git-buildpackage](https://honk.sigxcpu.org/piki/projects/git-buildpackage/), it will help you create the package directly from the upstream source git.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using uploading your packaging to salsa gitlab and using dgit as your packaging tool?

Dgit will allow you to make patches with git rather than quilt and also provide version control.

https://wiki.debian.org/gitlab/

https://manpages.debian.org/testing/dgit/dgit.1.en.html