# Debian packaging and version control

Tags: linux, version-control, packaging, deb

I am building a Debian package from a source tarball. The initial `debian` directory is created with `dh_make`.

It creates a directory `debian` in the directory my tarball was extracted to. I then customize the content of the `debian` directory to fit my packaging needs. Then I build the package with `dpkg-buildpackage -b`.

My question is: What is the best (canonical?) way to put the contents of the customized `debian` directory in version control?

Do I just copy it out of the source directory, keep it in version control somewhere and every time I built, I extract the tarball and copy the directory back?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/ may be better place due to nature of question

Comment: Fixme if my assumptions about process was wrong: you have `package-version.*` file, `dh_make` create subdir `debian` in the parent directory of src-tarball and fill `SOMEDIR/Debian` with build-artifacts, some of which you edit (and filling by **new artifacts** repeated on every new version of SRC-tarball)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Versioning of debian packaging Information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757832/versioning-of-debian-packaging-information)